# How high a mortgage can I afford at my current rate of monthly rent payments?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, first-time-home-buyer

I've been considering home ownership, and all other things equal, I'd like to know how much of a mortgage I can afford based on the rent I currently pay.

Not including heat and hot water, I pay roughly $800 a month on a two-bedroom apartment.  Most mortgage calculators take the total mortgage you get and calculate how much you'd need to pay per month to get that mortgage - I'd like to take my current monthly payment and find out what the highest rated mortgage is that I could get.

Ideally, I'd like a formula I can adjust - for X monthly payments, over Y years, at Z interest and tax.  That way, I can adjust it for any additional budgetary concerns (insurance comes to mind).

So, for $800 a month, over a period of 30 years, at 3.5% interest and tax rates, with 20% down, how big a mortgage can I take out?

Comment: I doubt very much that you can get a mortgage these days with zero down.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Any suggestion on what a reasonable down payment would be? Percent-based or otherwise?

Comment: A down payment of 10% at the very least is often the minimum required, and if you can put 20% down, your interest rate will be lower.

Comment: Don't forget property tax, home owner's insurance, trash, heat, hot water, lights AND repairs.

Comment: @mkennedy My current rent is $950 a month with heat and hot water, and I already have  renter's insurance plan, and padding for repairs. But I do recognize all of those will go up with owning my own property, and that taxes will increase that even further. $800 is still a generous estimate on what I can afford on a monthly mortgage payment, but mostly it's to give potential question-answerers a number to look at.

Comment: What's wrong with guessing plugging numbers into a regular mortgage calculator until you reach $800. I would use 4.5% interest just to stay on the safe side.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It would work, but it's a LOT less convenient.  And I'd prefer a good formula so that I can crunch my own numbers as part of a full budget.

Comment: A 200k mortgage over 30 years at 4.5% with 40k down would be ~$810/month

Comment: Look at #1 on this list: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/seven-windows-7-calculator-features-you-may-not-know-about/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Well, that's the very definition of convenient. :)

Comment: @DilipSarwate and Zibbobz, there is a type of loan that allows 0% down payment, which is the USDA loan (or rural loan). The only downside is that the house that you are interested needs to qualify for this type of loan, and the qualification is based on the location of the house. Here a link to check if the house that you are interested qualifies for a USDA loan: http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/welcomeAction.do

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - a $200K mortgage implies there's $50K put down. i.e. the total purchase being $250K.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer my mistake! 160k mortgage is $810. If the purchase price is 200k and you put down 40k then the mortgage is in fact 160k. If you use the Windows calculator like I did and plug in the numbers then it deducts the down payment from the total cost for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently use the Bret Whissel's [amortization calculator](http://bretwhissel.net/cgi-bin/amortize).  Fill in all fields except for one and click calculate.  The calculator will figure out the value for the field that was left blank.

For your example, you would be able to take out a mortgage of $178,155.99 ($800/mo for 30 years at 3.5%).  You could buy a house for $222,695 with 20% down ($44,539).

Answer (score 3):

If you google around you can find a few calculators that will do what you ask.  [Here](https://online.citibank.com/JRS/portal/template.do?ID=mortgage_borrow_limit_calculator) is one from Citibank and [here](http://www.mccuemortgage.com/calculators/how-much-can-i-afford-calculator/) is one from a mortgage company in Connecticut.

These estimate the amount you could borrow.  However, that isn't the whole story.  As Dilip notes, it will be difficult to get a mortgage with zero down.  The less you put down, the higher the interest rate is likely to be, and/or the more strict the lender will be about you debt/income ratio.  So even if the calculator says you can geta  $200k loan, that doesn't mean you can borrow that amount regardless of other factors (like your down payment).

Answer (score 2):

The calculator I'm familiar with is

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/buy-rent-calculator.html?_r=0

The benefit to this is that it calculates not just the actual mortgage payment, but all the extra costs to owning a home, which are extremely important to figure out what you can afford.